# Javascript binary search: match on greater or equal only?

Tags: javascript, binary-search

This search code returns the closest match. Often the closest match.x is smaller than target.x.

How can I return the closest match where match.x is greater or equal to target.x value and match.y is the closest y value?

Data is sorted ascending on x and then ascending on y.

```
var data = [
    {"x": 750, "y": 750},
    {"x": 750, "y": 850},
    {"x": 1000, "y": 500},
    {"x": 1000, "y": 1000},
    {"x": 2000, "y": 2000},
    {"x": 3000,"y": 3000}
];

console.log("Test 800", findClosestMatchGreaterOrEqual({'x': 800,'y': 800}));
// TEST 800 {x: 750, y: 850}

console.log("Test 2300", findClosestMatchGreaterOrEqual({'x': 2300,'y': 2300}));
// TEST 2300 {x: 2000, y: 2000}

function findClosestMatchGreaterOrEqual(target) {
    var low = 0;
    var high = data.length - 1;
    var item = null;
    var lastItem = null;
    while (low <= high) {
        var mid = ((low + high) / 2) | 0;
        lastItem = item;
        item = data[mid];
        var compare = compareItems(item, target);
        if (compare > 0) high = mid - 1;
        else if (compare < 0) low = mid + 1;
        else return item;
    }
    if (Math.abs(lastItem.x - target.x) < Math.abs(item.x - target.x)) return lastItem;
    return item;
}

function compareItems(a, b) {
    if (a.x != b.x) return a.x - b.x;
    if (a.y != b.y) return a.y - b.y;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you try to rewrite this yourself?  if so, what did you try?

Comment: function compareItems(a, b) {
    if (a.x != b.x && a.x < b.x) return a.x - b.x; -- This gets me closer, It now always produces a result where result.x is larger than target.x. But if y is a much larger value, I'll get a result where x is much larger

Answer (score 0):

Based on the statement `closest match where match.x is greater or equal to target.x value and match.y is the closest y value` I tried to change your function as below which will give you the desired output.

```js
var data = [
    {"x": 750, "y": 750},
    {"x": 750, "y": 850},
    {"x": 1000, "y": 500},
    {"x": 1000, "y": 1000},
    {"x": 2000, "y": 2000},
    {"x": 3000,"y": 3000}
];

function closest(target) {
 var arr = [],result;
 for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
  arr.push({index: i, diffy: Math.abs(target.y -  data[i].y),diffx: Math.abs(target.x -  data[i].x), x:data[i].x,  y: data[i].y});
  }
  arr = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(a.diffy) - parseFloat(b.diffy);
 });
  
  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i].x >= target.x) {
      result = arr[i];
        break;
    }
  }
  console.log(arr);
  console.log(data[result.index]);
  alert(JSON.stringify(data[result.index]));
}

closest({"x": 1000, "y": 1600});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your code isn't a  binary search

Comment: Sorry for that. But yeah this answer might be useful for some other people not trying to use binary search but want to achieve same result :)